# PHP calculating with decimals

Tags: php, decimal

I get some rewards from a XMl and want to calculate the sum. Why isn't the output for `$M_commission` 166.63?

```
$i = 0;
$commission_trans = 0;
foreach($responseXml->lead as $lead)
{
    if ($i == 0) {
        $last_trans = $lead->leadTime;
    }
    $commission_trans = $commission_trans + $lead->reward; 
    echo $lead->reward;
    echo "\n";
    $i++;
}

$M_lastclick = $last_trans;
$M_commission = number_format($commission_trans, 2);

echo $M_commission;
echo "\n";
echo $M_lastclick;
```

Output:
100.0 **0.63** 3.0 30.0 3.0 30.0 **166.00** 2013-05-10T13:42:01.058+02:00

I tried

```
    $commission_trans = number_format($commission_trans + $lead->reward, 2);
```

but same output.

Tnx a lot!

Comment: Please show `$commission_trans` value.

Comment: @CertaiN 166.00 , it is already there.

Comment: The expected output is 166.63 and not 166.00: 100.0 + 0.63 + 3.0 + 30.0 + 3.0 + 30.0 = 166.00 ?? - so its not working like above since there are some type caveats with xml strings as summands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "XML" indicates, this is coming from some XML stream (simple_xml?):

```
foreach($responseXml->lead as $lead)
```

and thus, the object members (`$lead->reward`) are Strings, not Floats.

The `$commission_trans` is initialized with a plain zero, so its an integer.

This line `$commission_trans = $commission_trans + $lead->reward;`  gives:

```
(int) = (int) + (string);
```

I would try to explicitly convert the XML string to a float:

```
$i = 0;
$commission_trans = 0.0;
foreach($responseXml->lead as $lead)
{
    if ($i == 0) {
        $last_trans = $lead->leadTime;
    }
    $commission_trans += floatval($lead->reward); 
                         // or (float)$lead->reward;
    echo $lead->reward;
    echo "\n";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: @Axel Amthor removed mine. There is someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I think flag `$first` is better than `$i++`.

```
$first = true;
$commission_trans = 0.0;
foreach($responseXml->lead as $lead) {
    if ($first) {
        $last_trans = (float)$lead->leadTime;
        $first = false;   
    }
    $commission_trans += (float)$lead->reward; 
    echo $lead->reward.PHP_EOL;
}

$M_lastclick = $last_trans;
$M_commission = number_format($commission_trans, 2);

echo $M_commission.PHP_EOL;
echo $M_lastclick;
```

Test on Ideone: http://ideone.com/1pi7mQ